# How to equally separate items in a printable area

Tags: android, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm writing a simple app in Android to print through a ESC/POS thermal printer. I need to equally divide the printable area among three different items so that they look justified. I am unable to find a way to print the same

am using these commands to feed into my printer 
https://reliance-escpos-commands.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html

attaching an image for reference, any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]
"Amount" to the left   ":" in the center and "value" to the right

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to easily specify it with an escape sequence.
For example, justification [ESC a](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=58) applies to the entire line, and cannot be specified separately for each part of the line.

Maybe you can try [ESC $](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=54) for absolute horizontal positioning.
That way, the string from the beginning of the line and the middle ":" could easily be specified with the same number each time.
However, the numeric string at the right end of the line will need to be adjusted according to the number of digits.

I don't know if such detailed escape sequences can be specified on Android.
Please try it.

---

In the library you presented, this page.

[Cursor Position Commands](https://reliance-escpos-commands.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor_position.html)

> Absolute Print Position - $1B $24
>
> Relative Print Position - $1B $5C